# Interactive tools to make math diagrams in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, templates

I'm looking if there are any interactive tools out there that one can use to make math diagrams for LaTeX. For example, [tikzcd editor](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de) allows one to easily make category theory diagrams and easily export the code. Are there other interactive tools which one can use to make 'free-body' diagrams (a diagram of a set containing elements etc.), directed graphs, knots, either by hand (using a stylus on a tablet) or from your laptop.

Thanks!